# Cocos2d error: File not found ( Xcode Debug area )

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I am working on a project using CocosBuilder and Cocos2d-iphone.The workflow is the following.I use some sprite sheet for my animations which I test first in CocosBuilder and then I publish them. All the images ( animations ) are fine in CocosBuilder, nothing's missing in all timelines but when I am testing it with the iOS simulator I have this error for some images ( .pngs ). So, the images are on the right folder ( resources-auto ) but Xcode-cocos2d can't find them. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how are the files added to the resources folder of the Xcode project?  You must make certain that they are marked (in Xcode) as members of the target. Otherwise they just sit in the folder and are not copied to the target as part of the build.

In exCode , view->utilies->show file inspector

will put the inspector utility on the right hand side.

After, click on any file showing in the resources folder, and you will see its target membership. Make certain those png's are members of the target you are building.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have a ccbPublish folder, and I keep my images in a Resources folder in Xcode. I'll try that and let you know. Cheers.